# Printing glossaries with long styles adds to the tables counter

Tags: longtable, glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package to print a list of acronyms and another one with symbols at the beginning of my document. Since I want my definitions to be aligned and occupy the whole width of the text, I decided to use the `long` style. This, however, changes the counter for the tables in my document, since `glossaries` uses the `longtable` package internally to create its lists. Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

I would not like to use `\setcounter{table}{-2}` since this is a reusable template and I don't always print both lists. I was expecting to have a more elegant solution.

Here is an MWE.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[acronym,symbols]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{long}

% my custom formatting
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{\linewidth}

\newglossaryentry{a}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{a}},sort=a,
description={A}}
\newglossaryentry{b}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{b}},sort=b,
description={B}}

\newacronym{c}{C}{The letter C}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{a} \gls{b} \gls{c} 

\printglossaries

\begin{table}
\caption{This table should be table 1.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `longtable` issue of using the `table` counter is well-known and is not restricted to the usage of `glossaries` and its various `long....` glossary styles.

Here is a small solution by defining a new `glossarystyle` based on the `long` style, replacing the surrounding `longtable` environment with `longtable*`, which isn't incrementing the table counter. You need the `caption` package for this:

```
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}% base this style on the long style
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
      \begin{longtable*}{lp{\glsdescwidth}}}%
    {\end{longtable*}}%
    }

\setglossarystyle{mylong} % Set the new style
```

The redefinition of `theglossary` is based on the original version, just replacing `longtable` with `longtable*` here.

---

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[acronym,symbols]{glossaries}


%\setglossarystyle{long}

% my custom formatting
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{\linewidth}

\newglossaryentry{a}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{a}},sort=a,
description={A}}
\newglossaryentry{b}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{b}},sort=b,
description={B}}

\newacronym{c}{C}{The letter C}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long}% base this style on the long style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
  \begin{longtable*}{lp{\glsdescwidth}}}%
{\end{longtable*}}%
}

\setglossarystyle{mylong}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\gls{a} \gls{b} \gls{c} 

\printglossaries

\begin{table}
\caption{This table should be table 1.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]