# Glossaries style=long* messes up table numbering

Tags: tables, numbering, glossaries, columns

I am trying to print a list of acronyms using the glossaries package (I also used glossaries-extra with abbreviations). My goal is to have the acronym on the left side (column 1) and the long form on the right (column 2). Therefore I am using the style=long. But this increments the table numbering by 1 so the first table actually is called Table 2 instead of 1.

MWE:

```
%arara: pdflatex: {}
%arara: makeglossaries
%arara: lualatex: {}
%arara: lualatex: {}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\newacronym{Test1}{Test1}{This is a test abbreviation}
\newacronym{Test2}{Test2longer}{This is another test abbreviation}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
  \listoftables
  \clearpage
  %\printglossary[type=acronym]             % This works
  \printglossary[type=acronym, style=long]  % Table numbering is off
  \clearpage
  
  \gls{Test1} \gls{Test2}

  \section{My first table} 
  \begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
      Col1 & Col2 \\
      Nonsense & Nonsense
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test Table}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

Using `\documentclass{book}` is a workaround since tables are numbered by chapter, but I really want to use article (or the KOMA class `scrartl`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just found this answer with a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266591/printing-glossaries-with-long-styles-adds-to-the-tables-counter It seems to be a bug.

Comment: arara calls seem to be switching engines? (not related to your problem)